# Youtube Video Player Fullscreen click event

Tags: youtube-api, fullscreen, onclicklistener, youtube-javascript-api

I am trying to add custom controls to an embeded YouTube player. I am overlaying a html menu.  However, when a user clicks on the full screen button within YouTube my html menu will no longer be available on the larger player.

There are two possible solutions I foresee.

First, if I could figure out the element that is generated for the fullscreen player then I could overlay controls on this.

Second, if I could grab the fullscreen click event I could use javascript to get the current available window demenisions an scale the video to the available realestate.

I found this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_fullscreen_mode?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FUsing_full-screen_mode

However, I am not sure if it would work in most browsers and second it looks like it is in the test phase.

The answers I am looking for are:
What is the element or how can I find the element that is generated for the fullscreen player?

Or

How can I capture the click event for fullscreen?

Comment: Did you find something?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to capture the click anywhere on the screen or on a link in a menu?

If you want to capture the click on a link on a menu I think this plugin can be useful as an example:

http://www.seanmccambridge.com/tubular/

https://code.google.com/p/jquery-tubular/source/browse/trunk/js/jquery.tubular.1.0.js

Comment: that first site is very distracting, maybe its my ADD but I got nothing out of what I was trying to read.  The YouTube Player has a button on the bottom right for fullscreen, that is the click event I want to capture.  I am considering using a chromeless interface and just building my own controls.